# Upgrade from gson 2.3 to 2.8.9/2.10.1 failed in deployment -java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19

Tags: gson, javassist

As gson 2.3 is vulnerable ,upgrading to 2.8.9 or any newer versions failed in deployment with the below exception.
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying ***: **invalid constant type: 19**

Compilation is completely fine .I am using Ant build system in my application
Anyone gone through such issue and upgraded  successfully?

Tried versions 2.8.0 ,2.8.4,2.8.5  everything goes success.
verified the manifest of the problem causing  newer versions 2.8.6 , 2.8.9 and 2.10.1 they result this Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7, JavaSE-1.8

I am using java 8 and in the Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment has  java 8 . So i guess java won't be an issue.But not sure .

Comment: Probably related to the `module-info.class` newer Gson versions contain. Is it possible for you to upgrade your (transitive?) Javassist dependency (see also this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/147))?

Comment: @Marcono1234 thanks for the reponse . Yes I  tried upgrading javassist to 3.22.0-CR1 and  Javassist 3.19.0-GA but still I could see  Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19 at 4 . And the git hub Issue link provided talks about jdk9 and i am using jdk8)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: @vennysuya, can you please test at least Javassist 3.22.0-GA (or better, just the latest version?) since as mentioned in the linked GitHub issue, that is the version where that is fixed. `module-info.class` is a Java 9 and newer feature which Gson includes for users of Java 9 or newer; Gson still supports Java 7 though. Some tooling erroneously (?) tries to parse the `module-info.class` file, so that tooling has to understand that Java 9 feature, which is why here you need to update Javassist.

Comment: @Marcono1234 yes you are Right !  3.22.0-GA is the fixed version for module-info .hence tried with most recent release which  resolves the problem . thanks for the  details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by upgrading javassist which sits in my jboss server lib folder . The version fixed as per this https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/147 is 3.22.0-GA .

**javaassist change :**
The "readOne" method in javassist ConstPool class doesn't have the module-info tag

[ConstPool class readOne method didn't have const 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyMZo.png)

**The fix in 3.29.0-GA** (recent release)
[ConstPool class readOne method has const 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7a4.png)